# C - Is there a way to write this in less code?

Tags: c

Edit : I understand the confusion. But I am not trying to optimize here, as @sergio said, I could not come up with a better word.

--

I have been writing code in JavaScript and PHP for a long time now, that I find it hard sometimes to optimize my code in C.

What I mean by optimizing is writing a program in less code. here is an example:

```
int i;

srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf(" %d ", rand() % 300);
    if(i < 10 - 1){
        printf("|");
    }
}
```

in Javascript I would have wrote it this way :

```
var html = ''
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    html += ' '+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)+' '+( i == 9 ? '|' : '' )
}
```

the difference in C is that I had to do the If in an other line, and could not act inline on the string. I hope you get my point.

So how would you write my code?

Thank you.

Comment: C has the ternary operator as well.

Comment: What is exactly your question? You could for instance shorten your C example code by removing the useless `{` and `}`.

Comment: C is not exactly a language for concise writing :)

Comment: Having fewer lines of code and optimizing have *nohting* to do with each other.

Comment: Leave low level optimizations to the compiler. GCC is pretty good at that. However, do optimize your algorithm (in particular the algorithmic time complexity)

Comment: @just.another.programmer: he couldn't come up with a better term, I guess.

Comment: In your JS, `i` will never `== 10`, but either way I would have just pushed random numbers into an Array, then did `array.join(" | ")`. It cleans up the code a  bit.

Comment: @user1689607 yes you are absolutly right. I was focused on my C program that I did not try to write less in JS, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Number of lines" is traditionally a poor judge of code, if you cram too much into one line it gets unreadable.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%s %d ", i ? "|" : "", rand() % 300);
```

Comment: As this is a function to print an array, this method here is pretty clear and very readable.

Answer (score 4):

Optimizing and writing minimum code are **different**.

In C, you could use the **[ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#C)** instead of your if statement if you want to just condense the code.

The assembly code generated and its efficiency however **probably aren't changing** as long as you have the same 1 conditional within 1 loop running N times, no matter how cool it looks, so focus on the algorithm, and not how concise the code is.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is in response to Murilo Vasconcelos:

Use http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to follow along.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0; i< 10; i++){
      printf(" %d ", rand() % 300);
      if(i < 10 - 1){
          printf("|");
      }
  }
}
```

Generates the following assembly using g++-4.8:

```
.LC0:
    .string " %d "
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movl    $458129845, %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    subq    $8, %rsp
    call    time
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    srand
    call    rand
    movl    $458129845, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %edx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
.L2:
    movl    $124, %edi
    addl    $1, %ebx
    call    putchar
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebp
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    cmpl    $9, %ebx
    jne .L2
    addq    $8, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

On the other hand this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>    

int main() {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf(" %d |", rand() % 300);
    }

    printf(" %d ", rand() % 300);
}
```

Generates this assembly:

```
.LC0:
    .string " %d |"
.LC1:
    .string " %d "
main:
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movl    $458129845, %ebx
    call    time
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    srand
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    sarl    $31, %eax
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    call    rand
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    imull   %ebx
    movl    %esi, %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    sarl    $5, %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    imull   $300, %edx, %edx
    subl    %edx, %esi
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

In other words, by changing the loop it allowed the compiler to unroll the loop, which should be a rather large performance increase that you wouldn't get without your change.  So don't let people poo poo you.  Check for yourself what the assembly becomes, not all hand optimization is a waste of time.  And, of course, test test test.

But, of course, you shouldn't optimize prematurely.  You should follow your profiler and let it tell you what your hot spots are, and where you need to optimize.

Better Algorithms first.
Then better code.
Then better assembly.

Comment: BTW, you've forgot the `for` loop in the first example! But I ran the example and see that indeed, the loop isn't unrolled when there is that `if` inside the loop.

Comment: You say "should be a rather large performance increase" but you haven't profiled.  I challenge you to measure even a 1% performance difference between the two versions.  Given the enormous number of branches required for a single `printf` call, removing one branch from the outermost loop just makes the code harder to maintain, since any changes to one `printf` statement have to be manually copied to the other.  Besides, `clang` will do it automatically even at `-O2`.

Comment: Between the two versions I measure a difference of about 3.7%.  It's clear that you didn't test it either.  Methodology is I redirected output to `/dev/null` and replayed the given code `1e7` times and used `time` to time it.  Which is not very scientific at the end of the day all things considered but with a difference of nearly 4 percent it's clear that there is a significant speed increase despite what you assumed.  10.23 seconds averaged for the first, 9.85 seconds averaged for the second, 5 trials, up and bottom thrown out.  Compiled using g++-4.7 `-O3`.  (Which is what I have installed).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: the OP edited the question.

If you want just to make an inline code:

```
int i = 0;
for (srand(time(NULL)); i < 10; printf("%d %s ", rand() % 300, (i++ < 9 ? "|" : "")));
```

Comment: You're doing work that the compiler will do for you.  Not an efficient use of your time.

Comment: @DietrichEpp yeah, you have a point, unless -O0 flags was used :P

Comment: You seem to have edited your answer, but I posted an answer in response to yours.  And also in response to Dietrich's comment.

Comment: @DietrichEpp you should see the Omni's answer. I thought the compiler would unroll both loops but it isn't what happens!